# Hit a curb, took a chunk out of the tire. Replacement?

Tags: tires

Was turning around today and hit a curb like an idiot. Noticed a big chunk out of the tire missing when I got home and wanted to know if I needed a new tire.

[image]

Comment: No way to tell how deep the injury is, if it is superficial then there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sidewall damage = replace tire. Tire can blow out at any time. Catastrophic if it happens at highway speeds. If tire came from Sams Club or Costco or sidewall damage warranty was purchased with tire, you are covered. Replace tires by axle pair most of the time.

Comment: Sidewall blowouts are definitely very, very dangerous.  Most tires have no extra mesh on the side so it'll just blow up and shred.

Answer (score 0):

I would change it. Although the tyre wall might not be showing steel its what it has done to the steel underneath the rubber, no one can know that, thats why they always say change them. Better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

i'm going against everyone else here, but it looks fine to me.  There are no bulges near the damage that suggest any underlying damage and it's not down to the metal.  That part of the tire (external rubber) is basically there to protect the inner bands and it just served its purpose.